# CacheCow and ODATA in Web Api

Tags: caching, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I'm looking at caching frameworks for my project and currently trying out [CacheCow](https://github.com/aliostad/CacheCow).

I have an odata enabled web api 2 project.

Simple controller test for a an Account entity.

Single get method that returns all Accounts. `/api/Accounts`. Cache works fine I can see the 304 response for subsequent requests.

Now if I do `/Accounts?$top=3` - that doesn't use the cache, which I understand as is because the query string makes up the part of the cache key?

So, how would I make `/Accounts?$top=3` read from the cache of `/Accounts`.

It's obviously the same data, I just want a subset and don't really want to hit the database to get it.

This is going to be even more important when using an AutoComplete control for example where its firing `contains(Name, 'xxx')` as the user types in the box.

Thx